# Different options to share files on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

When I right-click on a file and go to UbuntuOne, I am unable to select any option except "Hide Ribbon" and most of the time there is no ribbon to hide. So is moving files to the UbuntuOne folder the only option?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb mistake on my part, I didn't mention that the folder is outside the Home folder and U1 doesn't have the functionality to do that just yet according to the [U1 FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/CanISyncAFolderOutsideMyHomeFolder)

Answer (score 0):

I think UbuntuOne is working on directory basis, so you can put to cloud any directory (for example, ~/.config)

Comment: Tried right-clicking the directory to try syncing it with U1, but I am not able to do it. I've put in a screenshot in the question to explain my situation better.

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry I'm not in Ubuntu just now, but if you have no "sync" command in context menu.. maybe, try Dropbox? It can do it

Comment: It's not an emergency, but just curious to know why it ain't happening and if I can get it to work.